# Superoxide dismutase of Mn (SOD)

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I have a little problem with my paper about Mn superoxide dismutase. On this picture we have "B" behind the 3 OH ions, I really don't understand what is this. Where is this "B" from? Please, help me, my lecture will not accept my work today.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That ain't MnSOD, it's arginase.

B = boron

The molecule in red is 2(S)-amino-6-boronohexanoic acid.

See figure 2 of [Arginase−boronic acid complex highlights a physiological role in erectile function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10542097) *Nature Structural Biology* 6, 1043 - 1047 (1999)